# Should I choose a `set` or `list` of handlers in my event emitter?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Should I choose a `set` or `list` of handlers in my event emitter?

Performance aside, *what should/would the experienced programmer choose*?  *What other aspects are there to this decision*?

A couple of major languages go for lists.  Mine is going in an RPC framework, so it needs to be clear, easy to use, and also not accidentally trip up more complex use cases.

**Pros for `set`:**

- Less likely to have memory leaks (single handler attachment).
- Simpler API that forces clever people to be clever somewhere else.

**Pros for `list`**

- More expressive api usage (can add many of the same handler).
- Ordering (depends on implementation?).

```py
class EventEmitter:

    def __init__(self):
        self._handlers = set()
        self._event = asyncio.Event()
        self._data = None

    def on(self, handler):
        if not asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(method):
            raise ValueError('expected an async handler')
        self._handlers.add(handler)

    def off(self, handler):
        self._handlers.remove(handler)

    async def wait(self):
        await self._event.wait()
        return self._data

    def emit(self, data):
        self._data = data
        for handler in self._handlers:
            try:
                loop.call_soon(functools.partial(handler, self._data))
            except Exception as err:
                log.exception('exception in handler')
        self._event.set()
        self._event.clear()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use list when the order of data matters. As in a sequence. And if you just need the data be stored in random sets are generally better. If you would ask my advice. I would go with sets as they have better performance and when data gets large it will not suffer the same consequences as list i.e large read times.